# Zabbix appliance 6.2 - Can't login in to VM

Tags: virtual-machine, zabbix

We encountered Zabbix appliance 6.2 Can't login in to Visualbox. We tried root:zabbix / Admin: Zabbix / zabbix: Zabbix but still couldn't log in.

Is there any way to log in Zabbix appliance 6.2 in to VM?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OAMg.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OAMg.jpg)